# Display 3 last facebook posts on Prestashop

Tags: facebook, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm looking for a way to display my last facebook posts on my prestashop home page. I'm using facebook to push news to my community and I would like these news to show on my PS as well. Ideally I'd like my posts to be centered on my page and displayed in 3 columns for instance.

I can find a lot of modules to push products from PS to FB, but I can't find any to show facebook posts on PS.

I must be missing something...

thanks for your help

Adam

Comment: I guess you can't not take just the posts you want from Facebook, but you can use Facebook Page Plugin, and put it inside your PrestaShop. You can use a simple HTML content module for that. However, it's not a good idea because it will derive users from your shop to Facebook, and some will not come back. You need to derive traffic from Facebook to your shop, not from your shop to Facebook.